# Changing the disk scheduler on the fly

Tags: linux, io, scheduling

Can the Linux disk scheduler be changed on the fly by writing to `/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`? Should applications (e.g. Mysql) be stopped / started when changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the IO scheduler on the fly without fear. It is protected by appropriate locking to make sure no transactions are lost.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, and no, applications do not need to be stopped/started. This is by design, so that you can (relatively) safely try out different ones on a production system without downtime.

It does cause a "hiccup"; IOs in progress are allowed to complete, and new IO requests are blocked until the new scheduler is instated.

You can also have a different IO scheduler per block device (as seen by the kernel e.g. /dev/sda).

Answer (score 1):

1. You could add an 
   `echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` (as example)
   at the start of application 
   and another `echo` at the end with the initial scheduler .. 
   `echo cfq > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`
2. You can make a `cron` script that verifies the application start and change the scheduler accordingly.